# how can i get current Longitude and Latitude of user in telegram-bot-c#?

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to get user Longitude and Latitude from the location that user sent but when i send location i don't get any response.
on message event doesn't work for location message.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about your problem? Please read this and not be offended https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you want to get info about bot sended message??

Comment: Probably you didn't use `TelegramBotClient.StartReceiving()`